# Asymptotic form of $\int_{-1}^{1} (\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2) \, \text{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Obviously $\int_{-1}^{1} (\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x = 2/3 + 2\gamma/5 \sim 2\gamma/5$ for large $\gamma$. However, suppose we make the substitution $t = \gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2$. Then, $t \sim \gamma x^4 $ so $\text{d}t \sim 4 \gamma x^3 \,\text{d}x$. The integral is then $\int_{\gamma}^{\gamma + 2}\frac{t\,\text{d}t}{4 \gamma x^3}$. I'm tempted to just write $x\sim (t/\gamma)^{1/4}$ and just sub that it, but it doesn't work, so there's something sketchy about the fact that it's actually $x \sim \pm (t/\gamma)^{1/4}$ but I'm not sure how to take the plus-or-minus sign into account. This is mainly just a sanity check.

Comment: That ($t \sim \gamma x^4$) doesn't fly around $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This is completely overkill, but it's what I wanted to put my mind at rest. First, split up the integral into to parts:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x = \int_{-1}^{0}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x + \int_{0}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x 
$$

Switch the first one to an integral over $[0, 1]$:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}(\gamma x^4 - x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x + \int_{0}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x 
$$

Let $t_{1} = \gamma x^{4} + x^3 + x^2 \sim \gamma x^{4} \implies \text{d} t_{1} = 4 \gamma x^3 \, \text{d} x$ and $t_{2} = \gamma x^4 - x^3 + x^2$ for the second, so

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x = \int_{0}^{\gamma + 2}\frac{t_{1}\, \text{d}t_{1}}{4 \gamma x^3} + \int_{0}^{\gamma}\frac{t_{2}\, \text{d}t_{2}}{4 \gamma x^3} 
$$

Now use $x \sim (t_{1}/\gamma)^{1/4}$ and $x \sim (t_{2}/\gamma)^{1/4}$. Now,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}(\gamma x^4 + x^3 + x^2)\, \text{d}x & = \frac{1}{4 \gamma} \int_{0}^{\gamma + 2}\frac{t_{1}\, \text{d}t_{1}}{x^3} + \frac{1}{4\gamma} \int_{0}^{\gamma}\frac{t_{2}\, \text{d}t_{2}}{x^3} \\
& = \frac{1}{5 \gamma^{1/4}} (\gamma + 2)^{5/4}  + \frac{1}{5 \gamma^{1/4}} \gamma^{5/4} \\
& \sim \frac{1}{5 \gamma^{1/4}} \gamma^{5/4}  + \frac{1}{5 \gamma^{1/4}} \gamma^{5/4} \\
& = 2\gamma/5
\end{align*}

So I guess the key step is transforming the integrals to all be on the same branch.